# AlwaysOn AG between 2 sql server failover clusters

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, failover

I have 2 windows failover cluster and each of them consist of 2 nodes (virtual machines). And on each cluster has its own ms sql role which uses seperate shared discs :
1. wincluster1 (wsfcnode1 and wsfcnode2) - sqlclust1
2. wincluster2 (wsfcnode3 and wsfcnode4) - sqlclust2

For example on the sqlclust1 side I have Testdb database.

Question : Can I setup alwayson available group for this database between sql failover clusters?

Comment: For AlwaysON the requirement is that all the nodes should be part of the same windows cluster.

Comment: AGs can run between disparate clusters in 2016. What version of SQL Server?

Comment: I am using MS SQL 2014 Enterprise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2016, you can use Distributed Availability Groups, which is what you are describing. See more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt651673.aspx).

If you are using SQL Server 2014 or SQL Server 2012, the answer is no. You'd have to put all 4 nodes into the same cluster and then setup an AG with 4 replicas. If two of the nodes are in a different data center, you'd want those two replicas to be asynchronous for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [Always On Failover Cluster Instances](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189134.aspx) for local high availability and [Always On Availability Groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877884.aspx) for remote disaster recovery.

An example might be if you use replication, you can't currently make the Distribution database highly available using Always On Availability Groups. In this scenario, you might want to continue to use Always On Failover Cluster Instances for your local high availability solution where the whole instance fails over.

See the mssqltips article [Adding SQL Server AlwaysOn Availability Groups to existing Failover Clusters](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3150/adding-sql-server-alwayson-availability-groups-to-existing-failover-clusters/).

Scenario 2 in that link describes your configuration - Failover Cluster in Primary and Availability Group on a Failover Cluster in Secondary